# GCM extension for AIR on ios?

Tags: ios, air, google-cloud-messaging

Is the an extension for using GCM on AIR project in ios?

I know GCM works on ios native https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client

but I need it to work on Adobe Air

Comment: Take look at [here](http://myappsnippet.com/gcm/#IntroductionToAdobeAirGcmExtension), and you will get some idea.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about ios there